# Extjs 4.2.1 Iframe size issue

Tags: iframe, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am trying render `iframe` inside a container, but iframe is not getting stretched to full screen.

```
var htmlInputs = '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="AUD">';
       {
html: '<iframe scrolling="yes" name="iframe" src="" style="overflow:visible; display:block; position:relative; width=100%; height=100%;"  id="iframe"></iframe>' +
                '<form style="float:right;display:none;" method="post" target="ifrmae" id="ingenicoForm" name=iframeaction="https://*********">' +
                htmlInputs +
                '</form>' ,
            xtype: 'container',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function() {
                    var form = Ext.getElementById('iframe');
                    form.submit();
                }
     
}
```

Iframe is getung renders at one corner of the page as in image attached. I want to have this iframe streteched entire screen.

I have tried many things but still its not working,
Any help would be appriciated.

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxums.png)

Comment: height=100%:  id="iframe"></iframe>' <-- you have not closed the style attribute.

Comment: corrected still the same issue... its rendering in main container. and renderin at one corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var htmlInputs = '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="AUD">';
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            layout: 'fit',
            html: '<iframe scrolling="yes" name="iframe" src="" style="overflow:visible; display:block; position:relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 5px solid red;"  id="iframe"></iframe>' +
                '<form style="float:right;display:none;" method="post" target="ifrmae" id="ingenicoForm" name=iframeaction="https://*********">' +
                htmlInputs +
                '</form>',
            listenersss: {
                afterrender: function () {
                    var form = Ext.getElementById('iframe');
                    form.submit();
                }
            },
            width: 200,
            height: 300,
            style: {borderColor:'#000000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'5px'},
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: '<iframe scrolling="yes" name="iframe" src="" style="overflow:visible; display:block; position:relative; width:100%; height:100%"  id="iframe"></iframe>' +   didnt work

Comment: I have edited the post. It works.. something wrong in your environment..

Comment: Hi Arthur, Your solution is working, but how can i make container width and heighto 100% so that it will cover the screen.  If i am giving width and height in 100% its not stretching.

Comment: You can use viewport.